# My nuxt app works fine on CodeSandbox but not working on my local machine

Tags: linux, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've built a small nuxt.js app, it is working fine on the CodeSandbox, here is a link to it: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Ayman-Tarig/nuxt-test/tree/master/?fontsize=14

but in my local machine, it gives me an error saying:

```
 **Range Error: Maximum stack size exceeded**
```

this is my GitHub repo / https://github.com/Ayman-Tarig/nuxt-test

Note: I'm using nuxt version 2.6.2 on Linux Kubuntu 18.04 os

Comment: what node version? Did u tried to delete node modules and reinstall?

Comment: node version 11.13.0.

Comment: How to reinstall node modules ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reinstall your node modules.
The easiest way to reinstall your node modules is to delete the node_modules folder, and re-run `npm install`. Everything will be reinstalled.